# Outlook compose font looks wrong but fine in outbox/sent, Word, PowerPoint, printing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, fonts

I use comic sans 12. Always looked fine while composing in outlook. But last week it started looking thinner and more like 11 point. It says 12. Looks fine when in the outbox and sent folder. If I compose text and cut and paste it to Word, it looks perfectly fine. So the text is tagged as comic sans 12. Why is it now looking wrong only in the Outlook compose window? Don’t know what to look at the track this down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting default font in Outlook via File > Options > Mail > Stationery and Fonts.

Besides, how about change the message format to other type? HTML Rich or Plain.

Last, there could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

You can also try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Hope this can be helpful.